# Parking a domain Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Ok I know this question in many forms has been asked - but there seems to be no clear answer.
So here is what we have done on our cpanel WHM we parked a new domain on top of our main domain, we want to be able to track just how many people use the parked domain and track it just like you would the main domain, but we don't want to do and set it up as a new property on Google Analytics.

So I am wondering just how can we split the reports for one domain and  other domain but also have the master report for all traffic?

also do I need to add my parked domain into google analytics? I don't know where I do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same tracking code as in your main domain and set up different views filtered by hostname (create one view for the main domain, one for the parked domain, then go to `filters->new filter->prefined->include->traffic to the hostname->((enter domain name))` ).

You do not need to add the domain name for the parked domain in Google Analytics (the domain name is used mainly for in-page analysis which will in this setup not work with the parked domain).

Comment: How do I make a new dashboard with that view? I cant find the views in the reporting section

Comment: @RussellHarrower or Eike Pierstorff Can I do this with multiple unique domains?